# What is a Hybrid App for mobile?

Tags: iphone, mobile, mobile-application

What is a hybrid app for mobiles? What is basic architecture to follow while developing? What are the components? What will be the back end and what will be the UI? Is it for only iPhone or can be for any mobile device?

Answer (score 4):

With iOS, you can create an application that combines features of native applications and webpages.

A **hybrid application** is a native iPhone application that provides most of its structure and functionality through a web viewing area, but also tends to contain standard iOS user interface elements.
A hybrid application gives users access to web content with an element called a web view (described in “Web Views”). 
Precisely how you use a web view in your application is up to you, but it’s important to avoid giving users the impression that your application is merely a mini web browser. 
A hybrid application should behave and appear like a native iPhone application; it should not draw attention to the fact that it depends upon web sources.

You can create Phonegap app and still using native controls of cocoa for powerful features like Mapkit api, UIWebview (Childbrowser plugin) etc

Answer (score 1):

A hybrid app is a mobile application in which the same app can be worked in different mobile operating systems like iOS, Android, Windows, etc…, and even in browsers (Mozilla, Chrome, IE, etc.. ). It is the same as mobile applications for users, which can be installed from App Store or Google Play store. But technically it’s different, its works with a combination of HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

More read-: http://webduratech.com/what-is-hybrid-app-how-it-can-help-small-scale-business/+

Answer (score 0):

A hybrid application blends web views (loading a webpage into the app) and native code together to create a single seamless application. In most cases it is faster than developing the entire app in native code, because developing for the web is easier (there are tons of web frameworks and it is just easier to develop good looking content on the web vs via native code, such as swift).

Ex: Amazon uses web views for the products page on the iOS app, being able to reuse the code on iOS, Android and the web saves them a ton of time.

In a hybrid app, the core of the app (navigation, location) are normally done in native code and stuff such as showing images and information is generally done via web views.

Since web views are a web page, you can develop them in any HTML 5 framework you would like to use.

The most important part is to have an app that works and runs super well for your users, and having web views in the app is very tricky, but a huge time saver.