# Android app auto reset on minimize

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

We have designed an hybrid app which is a bit heavy (9 MB). Problem is that at times, minimizing this app (home button) makes the app reset in background i.e. its app cache is lost and app reloads from splash screen. After minimizing we worked with other apps in tablet (Galaxy 800).

We saw this problem only if we tried to launch app from the icon in launcher. This problem did not happen when we tried to launch it from the minimized list(recent apps button).

This problem is not specific to the tab. It also happened in Galaxy 3 and Droid Razr also.

Any guidance?

Comment: The terminology you are using isn't typical Android terminology. Can you explain how you minimize the app along with what the minimized list is.

Comment: @323go [here u go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211231/what-is-a-hybrid-app-for-mobile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem is that at times, minimizing this app (home button) makes the app reset in background i.e. its app cache is lost and app reloads from splash screen.

This is perfectly normal.

Computers, phones, and tablets do not have infinite RAM. Android's approach to this problem is to keep your process around for a while after the user has left it, but eventually Android will terminate your process to free up RAM for other applications and their processes. You can read more about the Android process model [in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Comment: but why it is happening on only launcher icon click, not when selected through recent apps?

Comment: @sij: When your process is terminated has nothing to do with how you then later re-launch your app. RECENTS may take you to an activity other than the launcher activity.

Comment: Opening the launcher may require extra memory that causes your app to be recycled that isn't required for the recent apps list.

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible that ‘deep clean' option is enabled by mistake on your phone. What deep clean does is, whenever you minimize an app , it releases all the memory associated with that app, and hence when you again open that app, it will start as if it is new. To check the 'deep clean' option,
go to the

> Developer options -> '**Don't keep activities**' -> disable it

If it is not disable please disable it.